# Explanation of Algorithm within EpiLink

Tags: classification, record-linkage

I'm working on doing some record linkage and have come across two choices for weighting and classifying pairs of entries. One being EpiLink proposed by P. Contiero et al. in "The EpiLink record linkage software"  Everywhere I turn for resources has a pay wall up and I'm just hoping for a run-down of the underlying algorithm within EpiLink.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There is an R package named RecordLinkage that describes the algorithm in the documentation. I don't think it actually makes clear how the weights are calculated (and neither does Contiero et al.'s paper). There is a term they refer to as the "average frequency of values" which I am trying to clarify. It appears that it might actually be the average proportion of values (which is just the reciprocal of the number of distinct values in a field, and is how I've implemented it).
EpiLink actually works surprisingly well (assuming I'm correct about the above, and it doesn't perform better than my experiments show). There is an approach due to Winkler that seems to perform better when using the Jaro-Winkler measure on suitable data (Contiero at el. advocate the Dice coefficient). I have something that seems to perform better than both.
I can be emailed at d_g_smtih147@gmial.com if you remove the underscores and correct the 2 obvious typos first.

Comment: That is the exact package I am using. EpiLink gives great results when combined with JW, I just wish I had a solid source of information on it's inner workings so I can properly present this work.

Comment: The R source code will give you that. Contiero et al.'s paper doesn't contain much more detail than the docs for the R package. The S value is just the weighted average of similarity scores. The suggested weight for a field indexed i is w_i = log_2((1-e_i)/f_i). I use EM to estimate the error rates, e_i, and assume that f_i is supposed to be the reciprocal of the number of distinct values in field i. Contiero et al. seem to just specify error rates via visual inspection of the data. Maybe you have the e-mail address of someone who could lend you a copy of their paper?